# Is it possible to automate clicks with xdotool to control a different GUI session from the one being currently used?

Tags: xorg, users, gui, session, xdotool

The `xdotool` command allows us to create scripts controlling the graphical user interface of the system very easily. I can e.g. open my Chrome browser in the following desktop by executing `xdotool mousemove 26 146 click 1`.

[image]

So, let's say that I create a new user to my system:

```
# adduser newuser
```

If I log with `newuser` in a different session and execute `xdotool` commands they work perfectly fine. But well, let's say that I've opened two different GUI sessions in different ttys, one with my **regular user** and other with **newuser**, and let's also say that I'm **currently running** a GUI session with my **regular user** and I create the following script:

```
#!/bin/bash

xdotool mousemove 31 61 click 1
```

Then I save it as `macro.bash` on my home folder and execute `chmod 777 ~/macro.bash` to set the right permissions for it. Finally, I open a new terminal and I log as `newuser` (while I'm currently using my regular user session):

```
$ su newuser
```

Now if I try to execute my script I get the following error (see EDIT):

```
newuser@myPC:~$ /home/myregularuser/macro.bash 
No protocol specified
Error: Can't open display: (null)
Failed creating new xdo instance
```

This script works fine if I try to execute it while running a GUI session logged as newuser, but **my goal here is to have a macro tool that can control the graphical interface of the newuser session with scripts while I'm using my regular user session**. **Is it possible? Does anyone know a workaround to solve this error?**

---

**EDIT**

As [quixotic](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/450352/is-it-possible-to-make-the-xdotool-command-control-the-gui-interface-of-a-differ#comment817590_450352) said in the comments and [telcoM](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/450387/103357) said on his answer I was missing setting the right values of the environment variables `$DISPLAY` and `$XAUTHORITY`. Although I didn't manage to solve my problem as described on telcoM's answer, I managed to solve it with the following process:

1- Logging into my `newuser` session.

2-  Inserting the following commands as the last lines of the `~/.bashrc` file:

```
if xhost >& /dev/null; then
   echo "export DISPLAY=\"$DISPLAY\"" > $HOME/.variableMemory
   echo "export XAUTHORITY=\"$XAUTHORITY\"" >> $HOME/.variableMemory
fi
```

3- Changing my script making it redefine the `$DISPLAY` and `$XAUTHORITY` variables to their right values while the script is executed:

```
#!/bin/bash

source $HOME/.variableMemory
xdotool mousemove 31 61 click 1
```

With this, I'm basically capturing and saving the values of the `$DISPLAY` and `$AUTHORITY` variables when I first log on the newuser session with the graphical interface, so I can use these values when I log with the shell later.

Now I don't see any errors and I can move the mouse around the other session with the `xdotool` commands perfectly when I execute the script, but I have a new problem: **The Xorg that is in a different GUI session is frozen while it's not being used**. To sum up, it queues all the clicks that I send to it and then it releases all of them at once when I manually switch to that particular GUI session (and that makes `xdotool` unusable)...  So, the question still remains: **Is it possible to control a GUI session with a macro tool while I'm running a different GUI session? Is there a Xorg configuration that disables this "freezing behavior" so it receives the click commands on real time even when I'm not using that session?**

---

**Additional information**

1. I'm running Ubuntu 18.04.
2. The display server used is Xorg (with Wayland xdotool doesn't work at all but this question isn't related to Wayland).
3. GNOME is the graphical user interface I'm currently using.
4. My main goal is to use a macro tool to control a screen that I'm not physically using, so I can use the computer while the macro does its job. Although I chose xdotool, Ubuntu, Xorg and GNOME to solve this problem, I'm open to answers that solve this same problem with different tools, desktop environments or even different Linux distributions... Thanks!!

Comment: It can control any X server you're authorized to.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams But how can I change the authorization of the X server in the context of my question?

Comment: the error you see is because there's no `$DISPLAY` set in `newuser`'s shell; `xdotool` uses that to determine which X server it should be talking to.

Comment: @quixotic Ah, yeah... That's true. I've edited my question now... Setting the $DISPLAY variable solved only part of the problem but my script still doesn't work completely.

Comment: can you give details as to how the 2nd user gets logged in?  via another VT?  textmode console or graphical?  if text how is the X session started?  what do you normally do to switch between the 2 users?

Comment: @quixotic I use the default configuration of Ubuntu (which I know that works the same with Fedora at least). Basically, once I configure the system to not login automatically on boot there'll always be a GUI interface to login into different users in my tt1 session. Any user that I log will occupy the next unused tty session available (tty2, tty3, tty4 and so on...). So I'm not opening the GUI session by the text mode console, I just use `Ctrl+Alt+F1`, then I choose the user and switch among them with  `Ctrl+Alt+F2`, `F3`, `F4` etc...

Comment: logging in on another VT may mean you're running into problems with the other session (on the inactive VT) being, well, ***inactive***.  you may have more success if you can carve out another seat, or run the second session in a **virtual** Xserver.  see eg https://dvdhrm.wordpress.com/2013/08/24/how-vt-switching-works/

Answer (score 1):

The other component you're missing is the `.Xauthority` file. It contains a "session cookie" that is generated anew each time a X11 server restarts, and the client is required to have it in order to send any commands to the X11 server. This file is normally located in `~/.Xauthority`, although you can use the `$XAUTHORITY` environment variable to specify an alternate location.

In order to control the GUI session that isn't yours, you'll need to gain access to the session cookie of that other session. If it has a different `$DISPLAY` value, you could simply copy that session cookie into your `.Xauthority` file using `xauth extract` and `xauth merge` commands:

```
su newuser -c "xauth extract /home/newuser/.Xauthority $newuserDISPLAY" | xauth merge
```

The .Xauthority file can hold multiple session cookies for different DISPLAYs at the same time.

Or if the session cookie is located in a file that is already accessible to you, you can use the `$XAUTHORITY` variable to point at it.

---

This is starting to seem like an [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem): you have something you want to achieve, and may have fixated on `xdotool` as the assumed way to do it.

But when you are trying to automate something, going through the motions of the GUI using `xdotool` is usually the least convenient way to do it. For example, if you want to automate starting Google Chrome as a specific user, you don't need to simulate clicking an icon: you could just arrange for the right identity and environment, and just start the process you want.

For example, to start `google-chrome` as user `newuser`, you might do:

```
su -lc "DISPLAY=<whatever> google-chrome" newuser
```

As the `su` command has the `-l` option, the `google-chrome` process will have the right `$HOME` for newuser, and so it will look for `.Xauthority` in the default location, i.e. `~newuser/.Xauthority`. You just need to supply the correct value for the `$DISPLAY` variable that matches the actual running GUI session of `newuser`. If you want Google Chrome to open a specific URL, you can specify it as an argument for `google-chrome` within the double quotes.

Comment: All users are supposed to have a `.Xauthority` file? In my case, I've realized that just my **regular user** has a `.Xauthority` file.  There's no one located in `/home/newuser/.Xauthority` and the value of my $XAUTHORITY environment variable is `/run/user/1000/gdm/Xauthority`. Would the command still be the same in this case? I see an error when I run it. I'm going to append the results in my question...